# Can a c# DateTime value be set to a specific invalid value (like double.NaN)?

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to initialize a DateTime value object with a value that does not represent a valid date because I need to distinguish an invalid or unset date from any valid value. For floating point numbers I would use not-a-number values like in this example:

```
Double value = Double.NaN;
```

Is there a similar value for DateTime objects in c#? For example something like that:

```
DateTime datval = DateTime.Invalid;
```

Comment: Why not `DateTime?` or `MinDate` ?

Comment: use nullable: `DateTime?` Then you can use `datval.HasValue`

Comment: "invalid" is a *vouge* word for `DateTime` instance since it always represents a point with date and time parts. Under the hood, it based on `Ticks` which is a long number and "invalid" term doesn't much meaning for it.

You have a few options in my opinion;

 - You can use nullable DateTime as `DateTime?` and then in can be *assignable* to `null`.
 - Or you can use `DateTime.MinValue` (but of course, this can be change which depends on what you mean by "invalid")

Comment: Thank you for the duplicate marking. I could not find the other answer because I was searching for "invalid value" but not for "null value".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a nullable data type - `DateTime?`. The same approach works with `double?` and is generally a better idea than using NaN, if you can.

If you can't use `DateTime?` for some reason, `DateTime.MinValue` is often used to mean invalid date. However, it still needs special handling in your code, just like `double.NaN`. Both allow valid arithmetic on the value, and may lead to unexpected overflows or other exceptions.

Finally, you can always make your own helper class. Something like

```
public class PossiblyEmpty<T> where T : struct
{
  private readonly bool hasValue;
  private readonly T value;

  public PossiblyEmpty(T value)
  {
    this.value = value;
    this.hasValue = true;
  }

  public PossiblyEmpty() { }

  public bool HasValue => hasValue;
  public T Value => hasValue ? value : throw new InvalidOperationException("No value");
}
```

Comment: Great hint! (off topic: For doubles I still prefer NaN because they can be used in calculations and produce an expectable result.)

Comment: @GeorgW. Yeah, that's exactly why I prefer *not* to use NaN :D If there's some unexpected input, and it's not explicitly expected and dealt with accordingly, I prefer to fail early. But each approach has their benefits and drawbacks, of course.